# Awk splitting a line by spaces where there are spaces in each field

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I've got an R summary table like so:

```
       employee     salary        startdate
 John Doe  :1   Min.   :21000   Min.   :2007-03-14
 Jolie Hope:1   1st Qu.:22200   1st Qu.:2007-09-18
 Peter Gynn:1   Median :23400   Median :2008-03-25
                Mean   :23733   Mean   :2008-10-02
                3rd Qu.:25100   3rd Qu.:2009-07-13
                Max.   :26800   Max.   :2010-11-01
```

and I need to produce an output csv file like so:

```
employee,,salary,,startdate,,
John Doe,1,Min.,21000,Min.,2007-03-14
Jolie Hope,1,1st Qu.,22200,1st Qu.,2007-09-18
Peter Gynn,1,Median,23400,Median,2008-03-25
,,Mean,23733,Mean,2008-10-02
,,3rd Qu.,25100,3rd Qu.,2009-07-13
,,Max.,26800,Max.,2010-11-01
```

so that in excel it looks something like this:

[image: output in excel]

However it doesn't suffice to split the fields by one or more white spaces,

```
 awk -F "[ ]+" '{ print $3 }'
```

It works for the header, but not for the remaining lines:

```
salary
Doe
Hope:1
Gynn:1
:23733
Qu.:25100
:26800
```

Is this problem solvable using awk (and maybe sed)?

Comment: Use awk `FIELDWIDTHS` instead of `FS` splitting?

Comment: Could work if I only had a file, but would it work with multiple input files where the number of columns changes and the field type could be different for each column? The only thing I'm certain about, if you look at the input file as having three columns, is that fields in each column has a ":"..

Comment: @SonicProtein no, you aren't even certain about that because the fields in the last 3 rows of the first column in your example do not have a `:` (they are just blanks). You're going to have to come up with some way to describe how a tool could identify where the fields are. If the fields aren't fixed width and leading fields could be empty, how could a tool tell whether `Mean   :23733` on the 3rd row is the first field or the 2nd but the first is empty?

Comment: export the data from `R` using <tab> ("\t") characters? Then use `awk -f"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{awk program}'`. Good luck.

Comment: @Ed Morton, yeah you're right, I'll try find a way to create a better output from R.

Comment: There is ONE possibility. If you can always rely on the first line of data to have all fields populated then you can figure out FIELDWIDTHS from that. Give me a minute to think about it and I'll post a solution based on that.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that R can output csv files, so if you have access to the data in R, there shouldn't be a need to parse anything trough `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS, etc. and relies on the first line of input after the header always having all fields populated. It includes the positions that are just `:`s as output fields, I expect you can figure out how to skip those if you do want to use this solution:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS OFS OFS:ORS)
    }
    next
}
NR==2 {
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,/([^:]+):(\S+(\s+|$))/,a) ) {
        FIELDWIDTHS = FIELDWIDTHS length(a[1]) " 1 " length(a[2]) " "
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    $0 = $0
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",$i)
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
employee,,,salary,,,startdate
John Doe,:,1,Min.,:,21000,Min.,:,2007-03-14
Jolie Hope,:,1,1st Qu.,:,22200,1st Qu.,:,2007-09-18
Peter Gynn,:,1,Median,:,23400,Median,:,2008-03-25
,,,Mean,:,23733,Mean,:,2008-10-02
,,,3rd Qu.,:,25100,3rd Qu.,:,2009-07-13
,,,Max.,:,26800,Max.,:,2010-11-01
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '1 {
   s/^[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)/\1,,\2,,\3,/
   b
   }

s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}:/:/g

/^[[:space:]]*\([^:]\{1,\}\):\([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*\([^:]\{1,\}\):\([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*\([^:]\{1,\}\):\(.[^[:space:]]*\)/ {
   s//\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6/
   b
   }
/^[[:space:]]*\([^:]\{1,\}\):\([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*\([^:]\{1,\}\):\([^[:space:]]*\)/ {
   s//,,\1,\2,\3,\4/
   b
   }
' YourFile
```

sed one, just for the fun if you need to adapt a bit in this ArachnoRegEx
awk is lot more interesting in this case mainly for any adaptation to add later but if you only have access to sed ...